# How to initialize values in angular2 typescript

Tags: oop, typescript

I have a class 'Rank' which contains a loses attribute and a wins attribute. Both of them are collected from a web service. I want to calculate the points attribute depending on them.

For Excample:

```
for(int i = 0; i<loses; i++{
   points += 1;
}
for(int i = 0; i<wins; i++{
   points += 2;
}
```

**Rank Class**

```
class Rank{
  $id?:number;
  loses?:number;
  team?:string;
  wins?:number;
  points: number;

  constructor(){}
}
```

Where I have to put the logic?

Answer (score 0):

I think You should do the calculation in `Rank` constructor.

```
class Rank {

  public points: number;

  constructor(public id: number, public loses: number, public team: number, public wins: number) {
    this.points = wins - loses;
  }
}
```

Points are not passed to constructor because they are calculated during object construction.
You can read about constructor purpose [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming))

Comment: I added this code: 
class Rank{
  $id?:number;
  loses?:number;
  team?:string;
  wins?:number;
  points: number;
  
  constructor() {
    this.points = (this.wins * 2) + (this.loses *1)
  }
}
but it does not work. The points attribute is not even printed to the console. The rest attributes are displayed because they are collected from firebase database.

Comment: You can try with `get points(): number { return this.wins - this.loses }`, so if you change the value of wins, or loses outside the constructor, it will be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your logic inside a setter in your Rank class like this

```
class Rank{
  $id?:number;
  loses?:number;
  team?:string;
  wins?:number;
  points: number;

  constructor(){}

       set newPoints( wins: number, loses:number) {
       this.points += loses; // from your code  points += 1;
       this.points += wins*2; //  points += 2;
       //or you can do it like this this.points += loses + (wins*2)
        }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I found a solution. I initialize the points value not inside the class but inside the component.

```
export class RankingComponent implements OnInit {

  ranks: Rank[];;
  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firebaseService.getRanks().subscribe(ranks => {
      for(let rank of ranks){
        rank.points = (rank.loses) + (rank.wins*2)
      }
      this.ranks = ranks;
      console.log(ranks);
    })
  }

}
```